# How would you express that you want to force a tiny bone stuck in your throat all the way out of your mouth?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> [spit](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/spit) 2 FOOD/DRINK ETC [transitive] to force something out of your mouth
>
> Billy stood up slowly, rubbed his jaw, and spat blood.
>
> spit something out
>
> Diana tasted her martini and quickly spat it out.

Now you have just eaten some fish and some tiny bones got stuck in your throat.

Now you managed to force these tiny bones all the way out of your mouth.

Is it correct to say "**I spat the bones out**"?

But it seems "**spit**" emphasizes to push something in **your mouth** out of it and not a good choice to say to force something all the way out of your throat + your mouth.

Comment: We say: cough them up. And it might even call for the Heimlich maneuver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a two part action, then 'coughed it up and spat it out'. If a one part action, "Coughed it out"... altho that is not a very common usage, probably because it is not a very common action. Normally we cough the thing up to our mouth, and then spit it out.